# PostGIS + ArcSDE mixed environment

Tags: postgis, enterprise-geodatabase

I'm trying out a mixed environment here at work with PostGIS and ArcSDE together.

I'm having some problems creating feature classes with custom SRIDs. I imagined that all that I needed to do was update spatial_ref_sys table, but it did not worked also.

Any tips on how to achive this with custom SRIDS? With normal srids it's working just fiiine.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Have you registered the PostGIS Spatial Column with SDE or are you using a Query Layer?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. I'm just trying to create a feature dataset in arcmap with the custom srid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create features with custom SRIDs if you use the ST_GEOMETRY geom-type, or do you get same error for both postgis and ST_GEOM geometrytypes?

Another question is: does your user have rw-rights on the spatial_ref_sys table within the public (postgis) schema?

Comment: Hello Peter, I cannot create any type of feature classes with custom SRIDS (independent of geometry storage type). When I last checked, yes it the user had rw rights on spatial_ref_sys. I'll check again thought! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to create a Feature Dataset then I believe (**this means I have not tested**) you need to register the PostGIS with SDE. As you use the sdelayer command line reference it seems this cannot easily be done for a Feature Dataset. I got this from the article attached.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/dotNet/index.htm#geodatabases/enhanci-205816615.htm

I will actually set up a test of this as I am unsure just thought it was worth posting

Have Fun,
CDB

Comment: Hello CDBrown, the feature dataset was just an example. I can't create anything with a custom SRID.

Comment: sorry for the delay my other work has gtten in the way, still on my to do list

Answer (score 1):

The SRID is embedded in your geometry columns, you cannot change it just by changing the spatial_ref_sys, geometry tables.. , you have to register it in postgis when you first load your tables (there is no function to change tables that already have SRID).
I am on the virge of finishing the mixed environment you are talking about.

First, load your tables in postgis with the SRID you want.
LAST, use sdelayer -o register to register it to the arcgis geodatabase.